# WordPress wp_pagenavi for CPT using custom wp_query() on another CPT single page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I know there were a lot of questions about how to use wp_pagenavi with custom wp_query() for CPTs, and I can handle it easily. But I've encountered a bit more complicated situation.

I have a CPT named 'project' and CPT named 'avtoritet_audiotape'. What I need to do - is to show all CPT's 'avtoritet_audiotape' using pagination, but on the single 'project' CPT - it's a kind of relation (for example while I am on page http://simpex/project/radioprogramma-avtoritet, where 'project' is my CPT name).

My code, which is working perfectly on any archive pages, or even single pages is:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?> 
    Information related to my single CPT instance 'project'
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'avtoritet_audiotape', 
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'meta_key' => 'audiotape_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    ) ); 
?> 
<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ): ?>
#Some stuff
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, pagination shows pagination links correctly, but when trying to access http://simpex/project/radioprogramma-avtoritet/page/2 - it redirects to http://simpex/project/radioprogramma-avtoritet

Is it possible in anyway? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> plz try this way.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $postArray = array('post_type' => 'room', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged);
  $roomPost = new WP_Query($postArray);
  global $post;
    if ($roomPost->have_posts()) {
        while ($roomPost->have_posts()) : $roomPost->the_post();  ?>
           <div class="post_title"> <?php the_title(); ?></div> 
       <?php
       endwhile;
       wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $roomPost));
    }
```

Comment: Still no effect =( And again, if I copy this code into any of my CPT archive page - all works fine. I guess I need some kind of hook to make it possible on single CPT page

Comment: have you set  Page navigation option in back-end.

Comment: Could you please specify what option? As I said before, I have several paginations on my site and all work fine, except the one which I can implement from another single CPT page

Comment: login in back-end go to settings ->select pagenavi you can see page navigation option.

Comment: I am sure there is nothing to do with those settings, everything works fine on all "archive-style" pages, and there is no any kind of option in settings to enable pagenavi on single CPT page :(